# Firestore query results out of order due to async call within results forEach loop

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I have a simple `posts` collection in Firestore with a `created` field set as a `Firestore Timestamp` at the time of document creation. Id like to query these documents and display them in descending order, i.e., `orderBy("created","desc")`

However, each document has a user record in the `creator` field stored as a `docRef`.  In order to display the posts correctly, I need to retrieve the user record for each post, and I'm using `getDoc` inside the `forEach` where I process results:

```
let posts = [];

const getLatestPosts = async () => {
  const pq = query(collection(db, "posts"), orderBy("created","desc"), limit(10));
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(pq);

  querySnapshot.forEach( async (postDoc) => {
    var post = postDoc.data();
    console.log(post) //logged in correct order

    //get the creator
    const userDoc = await getDoc(post.creator);
      post.creator = userDoc.data();
    }
    posts.push(post);
  });

  console.log(posts) //out of order due to creator query
}
```

Is there a way to use Promises or some other mechanism to guarantee the order of the result set after the forEach finishes?

I can't just add the user info into the Post document at create time since things like image and display name could get out of sync.  So I guess this is really more of a Javascript question than something specific to Firestore, but context matters I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you push the `post` to the array before you start loading the user, you guarantee its order and can update it later:

```
querySnapshot.forEach( async (postDoc) => {
  var post = postDoc.data();
  console.log(post) //logged in correct order
  posts.push(post);

  //get the creator
  const userDoc = await getDoc(post.creator);
    post.creator = userDoc.data(); // path the post in place
  }
});
```

Comment: :) I don't know why I didn't think of that.  Somehow I forgot that I retain the handle to post even after push.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the `querySnapshot.docs` property?

```
const getLatestPosts = async () => {
  const pq = query(collection(db, "posts"), orderBy("created","desc"), limit(10));
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(pq);

  let posts = querySnapshot.docs;

  // use for loop here so that it blocks before calling console.log(posts)
  for (post of posts) {
    //get the creator
    const userDoc = await getDoc(post.creator);
    post.creator = userDoc.data();
  }

  console.log(posts) //out of order due to creator query
}
```

---

Side note: Be careful that `querySnapshot.forEach()` does not block -- so anything you do after the `querySnapshot.forEach` might not wait for it to complete, and `await querySnapshot.forEach()` will not help. Note, `for (value of []) {}` does block. However, querySnapshot is not iterable, so you cannot use `for (doc of querySnapshot) {}`